# How to customize CSS of Angular Powered Bootstrap Component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have forked [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/hibumbapartha/ng-bootstrap). I want to create my own style for those component while I want to retain the complete functionality of ng-bootstrap.

But I did not able to find the CSS file in which I shold start changing.

Please help me.

**Note**: I have been able to run the code by `gulp demo-server`

Comment: you can set the variables and change the colors

Comment: I know I can change CSS. But I am not able to find the CSS file where I should change.

Comment: ng-bootstrap relies on the standard bootstrap css. if you want to customize ng-bootstrap components, you should customize bootstrap itself. See http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/